# .NET Core 6: Use jQuery to update a dynamic list generated from view model

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

So I have a razor view that uses a model as follows:

```
public class UserDTO
{
   public string UserName
   public int UserId
   public List<UserHobbiesPOCO> UserHobbies
}
```

```
public class UserHobbiesPOCO
{
   public int HobbyID
   public string HobbyDescription
   public int HobbyCategoryId
   public bool IsChecked
}
```

In the razor form, I have the following code used to generate a list of checkboxes to allow a user to select their hobbies:

```
<div id="hobbies">
   @for (int i = 0; i < this.Model.UserHobbies.Count(); i++)
   {
      <div class="hobby-item col-md-6">
         <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.UserHobbies[i].IsChecked" />
         <label class="attrChk" asp-for="@Model.UserHobbies[i].IsChecked">@Model.UserHobbies[i].HobbyDescription</label>
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.UserHobbies[i].HobbyID" />
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.UserHobbies[i].HobbyDescription" />
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.UserHobbies[i].HobbyCategoryId" />
      </div>
   }
</div>
```

Currently, this works as I designed it originally. When the form submits, it has a list of all the hobbies in the database and whether or not the hobbies have been checked. The hobby category is a semi-hidden field used for data analysis. The idea behind using a model to reflect the checkboxes was to ensure data integrity.

However, adding a new hobby requires a page refresh that resets all your data. So I thought I would create an ajax call that would append a hobby to the list and allow users to add hobbies without having to leave the form.

I have tried appending HTML using jQuery that mimics the HTML generated by the Razor code, but appending a checkbox item to the list that way does not update the model that goes to the controller on form submission. The new hobby generated by ajax just isn't there when I look at the model in the controller using debug mode.

It appears my efforts to ensure data integrity have come back to bite me.
Is there a way to update the Razor model via ajax so that is will be present on form submission?
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: *I have tried appending HTML using jQuery* - as long as you've appended correctly (correct `name=`) and appended inside the `form`, then they will be POST'd on submit.  Check the network tab to see what *is* being sent.  It's likely you're not building the HTML correctly, or there's an issue with the receiving controller action (eg if it loads the data from the DB then tries to populate with post'd data).  Please include the code you use to create new inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the HTML with Javascript is possible. But it is tricky with lists or array. Look into the generated HTML inputs for your for-loop. It should look roughly like this

```asp
<div class="hobby-item col-md-6">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[0].HobbyID" id="UserHobbies_0__HobbyID" />
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[0].HobbyDescription" id="UserHobbies_0__HobbyDescription" />
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[0].HobbyCategoryId" id="UserHobbies_0__HobbyCategoryId" />
</div>
<div class="hobby-item col-md-6">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[1].HobbyID" id="UserHobbies_1__HobbyID" />
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[1].HobbyDescription" id="UserHobbies_1__HobbyDescription" />
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[1].HobbyCategoryId" id="UserHobbies_1__HobbyCategoryId" />
</div>
<div class="hobby-item col-md-6">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[2].HobbyID" id="UserHobbies_2__HobbyID" />
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[2].HobbyDescription" id="UserHobbies_2__HobbyDescription" />
   <input type="hidden" name="UserHobbies[2].HobbyCategoryId" id="UserHobbies_2__HobbyCategoryId" />
</div>
...
```

Do you see the names of the input and the index? Be sure to insert them with your js-code. If the names and the index is right, the model should be posted as usual.

Comment: Yes, that works. My mistake was assuming any number would work for the index. To help with your solution, I also added a JSON property in the ajax call that shows how many hobbies I have, which functions as the index of the next appended item.